# Synchronization of if blocks, C++

Tags: c++, synchronization

The project I'm working on uses a custom implementation of critical sections. The way I create a critical section is as follows:

```
{
CriticalSectionLock lock(m_criticalsection);
...//Stuff inside the critical section
}
```

When the `CriticalSectionLock` goes out of scope, the critical section ends.

My problem is that I want to put the increment operation below inside a critical section (I can't use an `atomic_int`):

```
if (0 == g_envCount++)
        {...
```

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
{CriticalSectionLock lock(m_criticalsection);
if (0 == g_envCount++)
}
        {
```

But I think even if that works it's very confusing for the reader. Can someone suggest a better/cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I'd use an `atomic_int` if it's only the increment what has to be synchronized

Comment: @tkausl Unfortunately that's not an option here because of some platform issues. I'll update the question.

Comment: But I'm correct in that only the increment has to be synchronized, not the whole if-block, right? At least thats what your last code-snipped suggests

Comment: Why don't you do `bool envCountWasZero = (0 == g_envCount++)` inside the critical section and then test the condition and do the rest of your code outside the critsec

Comment: Whats wrong with [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9238ba5a334ddab5)?

Comment: @tkausl You're right. I just can't use atomics here because of some other issues.

Comment: Then I'd use @kfsone's suggestion or a helperfunction

Comment: @NathanOliver Nothing! I just want to make the critical section as small as possible. I only need that increment operation synchronized, not what's inside the if block.

Comment: Thats fair.  Ignore that then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only need the increment to be inside the CriticalSection, use hoisting.

```
int priorEnvCount;
{
    CriticalSectionLock lock(m_criticalsection);
    priorEnvCount = g_envCount++;
}

if (0 == priorEnvCount) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't priorEnvCount be out of scope at the time we do the 0 == priorEvnCount check?

Comment: @Adam D'uh, fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a critical section, use a `std::atomic<int>`.
The code would look like this:

```
std::atomic<int> g_envCount;
...
// atomically post increment g_envCount and return its current value
if (0 == g_envCount++) {
    // do something
}
```

Using the post increment operator, you automatically use sequential consistency memory ordering. If you want to refine the memory ordering constraints, you can use `fetch_add(...)` for it.

Comment: To quote the question: "My problem is that I want to put the increment operation below inside a critical section (I can't use an atomic_int):"

Comment: The question was edited after my answer. Originally he didn't say he can't use atomics.